# Not able to update OwnerId using TableauServerClient

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, tableau-api

While trying to update the owner_id of a workbook using TSC, I am getting following error:

400000: Bad Request
        Payload is either malformed or incomplete

Here is my code:

```
request_options = TSC.RequestOptions(pagesize=1000)
    all_workbooks, pagination_item = server.workbooks.get(request_options)
    for workbook in all_workbooks:
        if(workbook.name == reportname):
            id = workbook.id
            workbook = server.workbooks.get_by_id(id)
            print('Workbook fetched successfully')
            workbook.owner_id = '1234'
            print('New owner assigned to workbook')
            workbook = server.workbooks.update(workbook)
            print("\nUpdated {0} workbook. Owner is now {1}".format(workbook.name, workbook.owner_id))
```

Can someone please help me out?
TIA

Comment: Which line of code is throwing that error?  Are you able to print out the current owner_id's once you retrieve the workbook?  `print([workbook.owner_id for workbook in all_workbooks])`?  Are you passing in a valid owner_id?  1234 isn't a valid UUID for a Tableau user.  It should be something like `9f9e9d9c-8b8a-8f8e-7d7c-7b7a6f6d6e6d`.

Comment: On an unrelated note, I know you have asked a bunch of questions here.  Having used both this TSC and [Tableau Tools](https://github.com/bryantbhowell/tableau_tools) I can tell you I converted my code to the latter and did the same things with 30-40% less code and it was much more straightforward.  You should give it a try!